# Power BI & Dynamics CRM - Expand for lookups

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerbi

When expanding an lookup control in my **Power Query** are the Id, Name and LogicName attributes of the referenced record NULL.

It works when expanding the "CustomerId" attribute of an opportunity records, but it shows NULL when expanding the "AccountId" or "OwningBusinessUnit".

How the expand should work is outlined in this article: http://survivingcrm.com/2014/02/dynamics-crm-odata-feeds-power-query-whats-record/

I am using Dynamics CRM Online (Region = Europe) in version 2015: 
`https://<tendent>.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc//OpportunitySet`

So my question is: Why does the expand yield null?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this in the Dynamics CRM that I'm using and found that there are some opportunities that have null as the customer id.  This I think can happen when you create an opportunity but do not assign an account to it.  You might double check those.  Also I asked in someone from the CRM team to take a look at this question.

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story updates you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)

Comment: I limited to query to yield only those records where the account is not Null. So this is not the probelm. Even vor "not-nullable" fields (e.g. owner) will the  expand fail (no data is loaded)

Comment: Interesting.  Could you post the text of your query?

Comment: This is the query: OpportunitySet?$select=AccountId,OwnerId,OwningBusinessUnit,StateCode,StatusCode,TotalAmount&$filter=AccountId ne null

Comment: I tried it on my CRM and found that OpportunitySet query returned null AccountId for all the opportunities.  Looks like a CRM specific issue.

Comment: Ok then, at least it is not only me :)